# How to make the query for quartile 1, 2, and 3 in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query for quartiles like this:

```
cast(substring_index(substring_index(group_concat(`lulusanmagisterrangkuman`.`IPK` 
    order by `lulusanmagisterrangkuman`.`IPK` ASC separator ','),',',(((50 / 100) * count(0)) + 1)),',',-(1)) as decimal(10,0)) AS `Median`,
cast(substring_index(substring_index(group_concat(`lulusanmagisterrangkuman`.`IPK` 
    order by `lulusanmagisterrangkuman`.`IPK` ASC separator ','),',',(((25 / 100) * count(0)) + 1)),',',-(1)) as decimal(10,0)) AS `Q1`,
cast(substring_index(substring_index(group_concat(`lulusanmagisterrangkuman`.`IPK` 
    order by `lulusanmagisterrangkuman`.`IPK` ASC separator ','),',',(((75 / 100) * count(0)) + 1)),',',-(1)) as decimal(10,0)) AS `Q3`
```

But this source code is not working for floating values. When I try those codes, the returned value was an integer. What can I do so that the quartile can be seen in integer or float value? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:
you cast the values as `decimal(10,0)` - the decimal is defined with a precision of 10 digits, but with zero scale.
have a look here: [Precision & Scale in MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/precision-math-decimal-characteristics.html)
I changed them to `decimal(18,8)` in the statement below.

Furthermore, you don't need things like `(50 / 100)` - just use `0.50`

```
cast(substring_index(
        substring_index(
            group_concat(`lulusanmagisterrangkuman`.`IPK` 
                          order by `lulusanmagisterrangkuman`.`IPK` 
                          ASC separator ','
                        ),',',((0.50 * count(0)) + 1)
                       ),',',-(1)
                    ) as decimal(18,8)
    ) AS `Median`,
cast(substring_index(
        substring_index(
            group_concat(`lulusanmagisterrangkuman`.`IPK` 
                          order by `lulusanmagisterrangkuman`.`IPK` 
                          ASC separator ','
                        ),',',((0.25 * count(0)) + 1)
                       ),',',-(1)
                     ) as decimal(18,8)
    ) AS `Q1`,
cast(substring_index(
        substring_index(
            group_concat(`lulusanmagisterrangkuman`.`IPK` 
                          order by `lulusanmagisterrangkuman`.`IPK` 
                          ASC separator ','
                        ),',',((0.75 * count(0)) + 1)
                       ),',',-(1)
                    ) as decimal(18,8)
    ) AS `Q3`
```

Comment: Thankyou so much for answering my question. Your source code is working. GBU